# Splitting a table into three tables

Tags: sas

Hi I am trying to split a table into three tables with only one DATA step. When I am outputting rows to these tables I need to create a variable called diet_type to display either Diet One Diet Two or Diet Three.
This is my code for this entire dataset but I think the most relevant code is after the second data step.
This is my data
[i.stack.imgur.com/8gVka.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gVka.png)

Import and pre processing

```
options VALIDVARNAME=V7;
proc import datafile="/home/u54324957/The Files/Diet.csv" out=Diet dbms=csv replace;
run;
data dietfile;
    set Diet;
    First_Name=PROPCASE(First_Name);
    Last_Name=PROPCASE(Last_Name);
    FullName=strip(Last_Name) || "," || strip(First_Name);
    
    Length SexVariable $ 6;
    if Sex=0 then SexVariable="Male";
    else if Sex=1 then SexVariable="Female";
    drop Sex;
    rename SexVariable=Sex;
    
    diet_num=input(substr(diet, 6, 1), 1.);
    
    pre_weightlbs=pre_weight * 2.205;
    format pre_weightlbs 5.1;
    post_weightlbs=weight10weeks * 2.205;
    format post_weightlbs 5.1;
    weightloss=pre_weight - weight10weeks;
    format weightloss 4.1;
    drop Last_Name First_Name pre_weight Diet weight10weeks;
run;
```

The most relevant code : splitting

```
data Diet1 Diet2 Diet3;
    set Diet;
    if diet_num = 1 then do;
        diet_num = 1;
        output Diet1;
    end;
    else if diet_num=2 then do;
        diet_num = 2;
        output Diet2;
    end;
    else do;
        diet_num = 3;
        output Diet3;
    end;
run;
```

For some reason only Diet3 has any observations according to the Log.
Could someone help me to split the table into three tables?

Comment: what is data type of column diet.diet? based on your description, you need add a variable called diet_type, instead of trying to assign diet to 1 when it is already 1.

Comment: Show sample data that is in data set `Diet` ? Why are you splitting data instead of using a `BY DIET` or `CLASS DIET` statement in later code ?

Comment: I am splitting data so the data can be broken up into three tables based on the three different diets. @Richard

Comment: I changed the column to be diet_num which is numeric. @Bing Wang

Comment: I think I might need to add more code so the problem can be found.

Comment: First eliminate all of the other manipulations so you can concentrate on the conditional logic for the OUTPUT statements.  You can add that back once you get it working. Also why are you using PROC IMPORT to read a CSV?  Why not just use the one data step to read the text file and write the output datasets? That way you can control how the variables are created instead of SAS guessing how to name and define them.

Comment: @Nan, don't drop variable Diet from dietfile yet. Run a """proc freq data=dietfile; by diet_num diet ; run;"""" so we can see how many value 1 and 2 are there.

Comment: What processing are you performing on the split tables ?    In this exercise you are coding you can learn a lot about using `proc format` custom formats, `by` and `class` statements, `title` statements with `#BYVAR` and `#BYVAL` tokens and options such as `NOBYLINE` and label statements such as `label pre_weight = 'Pre weight (lbs)'`

Comment: Rather than posting a picture of a spreadsheet just copy the first few lines from your text file (use a text editor and not Excel or spreadsheet program to open the file) and past it into your question. Then we can see what your text file actually contains.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you probably don't need to split the dataset since you can always just use a WHERE statement to filter the single dataset based on the values of DIET_NUM.

Here is code that should read in your text file directly and write out all three datasets at once.  I included a fourth dataset to capture any observations where DIET_NUM is not 1, 2 or 3.

```
proc format ;
  value sex 0='Male' 1='Female';
run;

data diet1 diet2 diet3 other ;
  infile "/home/u54324957/The Files/Diet.csv" dsd truncover firstobs=2;

* Read in data, use in-line informats to give hint to compiler ;
* what length to use when creating the character variables ;
  input First_Name :$30. Last_Name :$30. ID Sex Age Height PreWeight Diet_num Weight10weeks ;

* Define the variables that will be derived ;
  length FullName $62 pre_weightlbs post_weightlbs weightloss 8;

* Clean up case on names and generate full name ;
  First_Name=PROPCASE(First_Name);
  Last_Name=PROPCASE(Last_Name);
  FullName=catx(', ',Last_Name,First_Name);

* Convert to pounds and calculate change in weight ;
  pre_weightlbs=pre_weight * 2.205;
  post_weightlbs=weight10weeks * 2.205;
  weightloss=pre_weight - weight10weeks;

* Attach formats to variables that need them. ;
  format sex sex. pre_weightlbs post_weightlbs 5.1 weightloss 4.1;

* Split into multiple datasets ;
  if diet_num=1 then output diet1;
  else if diet_num=2 then output diet2;
  else if diet_num=3 then output diet3;
  else output other;

run;
```